# Repetitive match in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, match

I have a problem when trying to use the result of match function in one new match.

This is the code:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

p="somelongtextmelongtextmelongtextmelongtext";

f1 = p.match(/some/g);

document.write(f1);

f2 = f1.match(/om/g);

document.write(f2);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The output is the word "some" when it must be "om". I don't understand this behavior and I need the output of f1 in a more complex situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that you pasted the exact same code that you're testing?

I ask because `f1 = p.match(/some/g);` returns an array of matches, and the `Array` object does not have a `.match` method, so `f1.match(/om/g);` should throw an error.

Anyways, the correct way to do this is:

```
p="somelongtextmelongtextmelongtextmelongtext";
f1 = p.match(/some/g);
if (f1) {
    f2 = f1[0].match(/om/g);
    console.log(f2);
}
```

Comment: Yes. that's the code. I was confused because I always saw the result as a string, because the format was match1,match2,etc... and the document.write(f1); showed valid output without the use of an array format. Thank you very much.

Comment: Using console is better than using document.write to test stuff. It would show you an array and not the toString() equivalent of the array.

Comment: edited my answer to use `console.log` per @epascarello's comment

Comment: Thanks. I tested the Chrome console and it said: "Object some has no method 'match'" Both ways (digitalbath and joseluisrod) works!

Answer (score 0):

the output is "some" because it is failing on the line: f2 = f1.match(/om/g); it never gets to writing f2.

f1 is an object variable, not a string. the object doesn't have a match method. replace the offfending line with this:

f2 = f1.toString().match(/om/g);

HTH

Comment: This isn't really correct as the `.match()` method may return an array with multiple matches, and `Array.toString()` will concatenate all the matches with comma characters, making the send `.match` potentially match things you don't want.